# Near Pagoda Trying to connect to https://rpc.testnet.near.org/ but getting CORS

Tags: javascript, frontend, nearprotocol, near, near-api-js

folks, trying to connect to Pagoda via near-api-js

```
const CONTRACT_NAME = process.env.CONTRACT_NAME || 'mycontract.testnet'
const API_KEY = '06cffba5-e0c5-bla-bla-blablabla';
const keyStore = new keyStores.BrowserLocalStorageKeyStore();
```

My config looks like this:

```
   {
      networkId: 'testnet',
      nodeUrl: 'https://rpc.testnet.near.org/',
      keyStore,
      contractName: CONTRACT_NAME,
      walletUrl: 'https://wallet.testnet.near.org',
      helperUrl: 'https://helper.testnet.near.org',
      explorerUrl: 'https://explorer.testnet.near.org',
      headers: {
        'x-api-key': API_KEY,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    }
```

And getting this error, when I remove headers, everything works perfectly, but I can't connect to Pagoda :)

```
Access to fetch at 'https://rpc.testnet.near.org/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```